# Powershell : unable to add the members to collections

Tags: powershell, powercli

I face a problem in following test script.
I expect the following result as the output of it.

```
VM Name        vCPU               Memory                                                 
-------         ----               ------                                        
Server1          1                                                                         
Server2                               8
```

unfortunately, i am receiving the following output. Can someone help me to understand the mistake in the code?

```
enter code here

VM Name        vCPU                                                 
-------        ----                                                                                                
Server1         1                                                                                                   
Server2
```

---

```
$obj_collection = @()  
    $report_data = New-Object System.Object  
    $report_data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "VM Name" -Value "Server1"  
    $report_data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "vCPU" -Value "1"  

    $obj_collection += $report_data  
  $report_data = New-Object System.Object  
    $report_data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "VM Name" -Value "Server2"  
    $report_data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Memory" -Value "8"  
  $obj_collection += $report_data  
  $obj_collection
```

Answer (score 0):

this? You need to add apple with apple because apple with potatoes can give strange behaviour

```
$obj_collection = @()  
    $report_data = New-Object System.Object  
    $report_data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "VM Name" -Value "Server1"  
    $report_data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "vCPU" -Value "1"
    $report_data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Memory" -Value $null   

    $obj_collection += $report_data  
  $report_data = New-Object System.Object  
    $report_data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "VM Name" -Value "Server2"
     $report_data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "vCPU" -Value $null  
    $report_data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Memory" -Value "8"  
  $obj_collection += $report_data  
  $obj_collection
```